# Is it possible to define sharepoint workflows from powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I am able to create workflows using SharePoint designer; however, can this (including the adding of actions and conditions) also be accomplished in PowerShell?  Is this demonstrated in a book or in some resource online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

No

**Long Answer**

Sharepoint 2013 Workflows uses the Workflow Manager service. Windows Workflow Foundation (WF), in turn, is built on the messaging functionality that is provided by Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).

Workflows are a structured collection of workflow "activities," each of which represents a functional component of a business process.

The activities, which are implementations of activity classes, are implemented declaratively by using **XAML.**

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163181(v=office.15).aspx)

XAML file is like an XML file, so if you want you can edit this file in PowerShell as if it were an XML file, but I think is better to use Sharepoint Designer or Visual Studio.